# PHP imap_fetchbody

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I have been trying to fetch message but unsuccessful.

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 0);
```

the messages without attachments are good and I have output but with attachments
gives some complicated outputs out of which both html and plain message are encoded with some (Content-Type) which is a part of gmail messages

Comment: Messages with attachments usually come as multipart, divided with a boundary string. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just just want to get the text part of the messages?

Comment: yes, I just need the  text message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the plain text part of a multipart email body:

```
<?php

//get the body
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 0);

//parse the boundary separator
$matches = array();
preg_match('#Content-Type: multipart\/[^;]+;\s*boundary="([^"]+)"#i', $body, $matches);
list(, $boundary) = $matches;

$text = '';
if(!empty($boundary)) {
    //split the body into the boundary parts
    $emailSegments = explode('--' . $boundary, $body);

    //get the plain text part
    foreach($emailSegments as $segment) {
        if(stristr($segment, 'Content-Type: text/plain') !== false) {
            $text = trim(preg_replace('/Content-(Type|ID|Disposition|Transfer-Encoding):.*?\r\n/is', '', $segment));
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: i have trying your code but the list(, $boundary) = $matches; is having error of Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1.0);
```

this seems to be the only one working for me. I think the first integer in the last parameter represents the section of the email, so if it starts with a zero it will contain all the header information. If it starts with a one then it contains the message information. Then the second integer followed by the period is the section of that section. So when I put zero it shows information, but when I put one or two it doesn't show anything for some emails.

Comment: More details: [`imap_fetchbody` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php). [IMAP4 specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

Answer (score 0):

This helped

> $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1.1);

Comment: This won't work in all cases.  MIME is very flexible.